# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll

Tags: c#, .net, linq, windows-phone-7

I am getting the error below and I don't know why, because my application was running normal 4 hours ago, but now isn't working and I did not changed anything..

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Linq.dll

I am getting the error in the line `db.SubmitChanges();`.. I am leaving the full code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Aplicativo_Windows_Phone
{
    public partial class AddColetor : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string email;

        public AddColetor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("email", out email);
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AppDataContext db = new AppDataContext();
            Coletor coletor = new Coletor();
            if (rdNorte.IsChecked == true)
            {
                coletor.Latitude = Convert.ToInt32(txtLat.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                coletor.Latitude = Convert.ToInt32(txtLat.Text) - (2 * Convert.ToInt32(txtLat.Text));
            }

            if (rdLeste.IsChecked == true)
            {
                coletor.Longitude = Convert.ToInt32(txtLong.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                coletor.Longitude = Convert.ToInt32(txtLong.Text) - (2 * Convert.ToInt32(txtLong.Text));
            }

            if (txtLat.Text != "" && txtLong.Text != "" && rdNorte.IsChecked == true || rdSul.IsChecked == true && rdLeste.IsChecked == true || rdOeste.IsChecked == true)
            {
                foreach (var pessoa in db.Pessoas)
                {
                    if (pessoa.Email == email)
                    {
                        pessoa.Coletores.Add(coletor);
                    }
                }

                db.Coletores.InsertOnSubmit(coletor);
                db.SubmitChanges();

                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ColetoresPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Preencha todos os campos e marque as opções para adicionar um coletor");
            }
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ColetoresPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }

    }
}
```

The Coletor class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data.Linq;
using Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq;
using Microsoft.Phone.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace Aplicativo_Windows_Phone
{
#pragma warning disable 0169, 0649
    [Table(Name = "Coletores")]
    public class Coletor
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public float Latitude { get; set; }

        [Column]
        public float Longitude { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "Pessoa")]
        private int? pessoaId;

        private EntityRef<Pessoa> _pessoa = new EntityRef<Pessoa>();

        [Association(Name = "FK_Coletores_ColetorPessoa", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_pessoa", ThisKey = "pessoaId")]
        public Pessoa Pessoa
        {
            get { return _pessoa.Entity; }
            set { _pessoa.Entity = value; }
        }

        private EntitySet<Ocorrencia> _ocorrencias = new EntitySet<Ocorrencia>();

        [Association(Name = "FK_Ocorrencias_ColetorOcorrencias", Storage = "_ocorrencias", ThisKey = "Id", OtherKey = "coletorId")]
        public ICollection<Ocorrencia> Ocorrencias
        {
            get { return (from co in ColetorOcorrencias select co.Ocorrencia).ToList(); }
            set { _ocorrencias.Assign(value); }
        }

        private EntitySet<PessoaColetor> _pessoaColetores = new EntitySet<PessoaColetor>();

        [Association(Name = "FK_PessoaColetores_Coletores", Storage = "_pessoaColetores", OtherKey = "coletorId", ThisKey = "Id")]
        private ICollection<PessoaColetor> PessoaColetores
        {
            get { return _pessoaColetores; }
            set { _pessoaColetores.Assign(value); }
        }

        private EntitySet<ColetorOcorrencia> _coletorOcorrencias = new EntitySet<ColetorOcorrencia>();

        [Association(Name = "FK_ColetorOcorrencias_Coletores", Storage = "_coletorOcorrencias", OtherKey = "coletorId", ThisKey = "Id")]
        private ICollection<ColetorOcorrencia> ColetorOcorrencias
        {
            get { return _coletorOcorrencias; }
            set { _coletorOcorrencias.Assign(value); }
        }

        public ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas
        {
            get { return (from pc in PessoaColetores select pc.Pessoa).ToList(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually exceptions include a message as well.  Is there any other information provided with the error?

Comment: Actually there is no other information. I could show an image of the problem but I don't know how to attach an image here.

Comment: What is 'coletor'? Are you violating any constraints (unique keys, for example)?

Comment: Coletor is a class, and I am not violating.. It is very strange because my program was running normal, but then, suddenly just stopped. I am leaving the Coletor class in the question.

Comment: From your code, it looks like you're using LinqToSql; is that correct?

Comment: There was an inner exception.  The exception dialog has a link on it that says "copy exception details to the clipboard" near the bottom.  In future, click that link and paste the details into your question.  That usually has all the information we need to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know why, but now my application is working. I think that this error is a kind of bug from Visual Studio, so, to fix my problem, I just restarted my computer.

Comment: Didn't you call tech support?  Have you tried restarting your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Gonna go out on a limb here based on past experience.  The SqlServerCE driver comes in 2 flavors, x86 and x64.  Normally, only one can installed on the machine and the installer will fail on the second.  However if the x86 driver is installed first then the x64, it is possible to use a /force switch on the commandline.

This may help your problem, or it may not, hard to tell from the detail provided.

Comment: This is Windows Phone, running an ARM OS without any installable drivers.